# nullable types in c#

Tags: c#, java, c#-4.0

I am a `java` beginner and I have to compare `null` values in java with null in `C#`.

I read that java does not assume anything to be null and always allocates memory but c# on the contrary assumes all to be null??? (did not understand what does this mean)

I also read that ordinary types in c# cannot be null but then i saw a code which says :

```
int? a = null;
```

int is ordinary type right?

I am really getting confused , can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: int and int? are not the same object. int? is a nullable object of type int

Answer (score 3):

int is a primitive struct, yes.
However,

```
int?
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
Nullable<int>
```

which is a completely different type.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: Hey.. thanks a lot... does that mean they are similar to generics in java?

Comment: The System.Nullable class is a generic type, meaning it can hold various other types, but the concept of generics is not equivalent to the concept of the System.Nullable class itself, no.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx):

> Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct. A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value.

```
class NullableExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int? num = null;

        // Is the HasValue property true? 
        if (num.HasValue)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = " + num.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = Null");
        }

        // y is set to zero 
        int y = num.GetValueOrDefault();

        // num.Value throws an InvalidOperationException if num.HasValue is false 
        try
        {
            y = num.Value;
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`null` is pretty similar in C# and Java. C#'s `struct`s cannot be null, with the exception of [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is itself a `struct`, but through some compiler magic can pretend to have a `null` value). Java's primitives cannot be null.

`int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`. See [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) for more info on that.